# Twilio. Call remains active on wifi down or app kill

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

When two users are in a voip to voip call, and one either looses the wi-fi connection or kills the app (throws it from memory), I don't have time and i am not able to call the disconnect method. And on the other end the user's call remains active. 
I waited 80 seconds for it to throw a timeout or something and disconnect automatically, but to no avail.
Any ideas on what the best practice is to handle this scenario ?

Is there a way to perhaps treat this on the server-side ?!

Comment: Don't have time means ? onDestroy() of activity will still be called there you can call the disconnect method

Comment: @VivekMishra onDestroy() of activity in some of situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.
Based on this answer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy%28%29